# Matlab overlaying color on an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a grascale image where I want to overlay different colors to different areas that have similar properties (say direction or intensity etc.) I am not referring to a heat map. Rather I have hard coded segmentation code where I have grouped pixels together by their "similarities". Now I want to over lay colors to those pixels.

For example, for a 3x3 pixel pic, say I know that the top row and bottom row are similar group. And the middle row is another group. How can I overlay a red hue with one group and a blue hue with another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image overlay with matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524886/image-overlay-with-matrix)

Comment: The difference here is that my pixel fvalues are not normalized. I looked for specific patterns in my segmentation code. So the matrix could have something like $ 0.2 0.3 0.35$ and $0.8 0.8 0.85$ for pixel intensity in top and bottom row but I want them to show as the same color/hue. I am grouping by other properties other than color intensity. Heat map will seperate those two rows as having two different colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your 3x3x1 grayscale image into a 3x3x3 color image, and then adjust the hue values for the pixels you want.

So say:

```
GreyImg=[0.2, 0.3, 0.35;...
         0.5, 0.6, 0.56;...
         0.8, 0.8, 0.85];
%Convert To Color Img
ColorImg(:,:,1)=GreyImg;
ColorImg(:,:,2)=GreyImg;
ColorImg(:,:,3)=GreyImg;

%Add a red hew to top row:
ColorImg(1:1,:,1)=ColorImg(1:1,:,1)+[.2, .2, .2];
%Add a blew hew to top row:
ColorImg(3:3,:,3)=ColorImg(3:3,:,3)+[.2, .2, .2];

imshow(ColorImg);
```