# How to overly depth data on 2D image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mesh, surface

All of this is done in Matlab. I have a 2D RGB image, with *some* depth data for key vertexes. That is, I have three vectors (m x 1): X, Y, Z. Together, [X(i), Y(i)] specifies the point in the image with depth Z(i).

The crux of my problem is this:

> I would like to plot the image "warped" with the depth information. But, each time I keep calling functions like 'mesh(X,Y,Z,RGBImage)' and 'surf', I get weird errors like "Z need to be matrix not vector". Also, I haven't even been able to implement the 'warp' function, as I am not sure how to translate my data into a usable format.

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: I finally got it to work the way I would like. The only thing that needed to be changed, that was not answered, was to include the line

```
s = surf(Xmat,Ymat,Zmat, T1, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'FaceColor', ... 
'texturemap');
```

Where 
`T1 = rgb2gray(OrignialRGBImage);`. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to MATLAB right now, so I am giving the outline of the solution.

First, create two matrices using meshgrid: `[Xmat,Ymat] = meshgrid(1:imgCols,1:imgRows);`. Now, you can find every row of `[X,Y]` at `[Xmat(i,j),Ymat(i,j)]` for some `(i,j)`. In the next step, create `Zmat` such that `Zmat(i,j)` is the correct depth value for `[Ymat(i,j),Xmat(i,j)]`. You should be able to do this as follows:

```
Zmat = zeros(imgRows,imgCols);
for i=1:size(X,1)
   Zmat(Y(i),X(i))=Z(i);
end
```

Now you can do `surf` with `Xmat,Ymat,Zmat` as follows. Then overlay image as texture.

```
s = surf(Xmat,Ymat,Zmat);
set(s, 'faceColor', 'texture','edgecolor', 'none','cdata', subimage); %not tested,
                                                                      %see if it works
```

Overlaying part taken from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/68633-how-to-overlay-the-image-on-the-surface).

If the above part doesn't work, then you can overlay  `Zmat` in the heatmap style, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524886/image-overlay-with-matrix).

Comment: Ok. Glad to know. I was sure some adjustments would be needed since I couldn't run this code to check the correctness.